# Upload progress bar on contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, progress-bar, contact-form-7

I have a friend which has this website and has clients uploading big files to his contact form all the time. As the form does not say the percentage of upload, often people just go away cause they think the website is blocked. This is the contact form url

http://www.smalllinks.com/68G7

The only way to avoid this would be to build a contact form that has an upload progress bar. As he i programmed the website in Wordpress and i have always used contact form 7 (which is hooked to another plugin for a database so unfortunately we cannot change). I have looked all over the net to make this little hack to the form and I have even found this fix

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-progress-bar-in-file-upload-on-submit-form

but unfortunately it does not seem to work on the current contact form 7 plugin (i think the folder structure changed.

Anybody could kindly help me to find a quick solution for it? A small hack or something? I just need a progress bar for the upload.

Thanks a lot

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The instructions in the link you provided still work with minor modifications to step 1...

In /wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/contact-form.php after:
`$html .= '</form>';`

Add:

`$html .= '<div id="progressbox"><div id="progressbar"></div ><div id="statustxt">0%</div ></div><div id="output2"></div>';`

Follow the rest of the instructions as is and you should be good to go. I got this to work with CF7 version 4.1.2.

Comment: Is this still working? I have followed the instructions, but it shows 0% all the time

Comment: I had the same problem. But then I noticed that if you use copy/paste for writing the code
`<script src=”http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js”></script>` after the `</body>` tag in the template.php, you must replace the `" "`.